# How can I convert a str type to date type using python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I'm trying to convert a str type ( like :"1995-01-09 00:00:00") to date, here is my attempt

```
for line in ratings_df[['user_id','movie_id','rating','timestamp']].values:
    annee= line[3]
    print datetime.strptime(annee, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and I got this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Please `print annee` to confirm you're working with the kind of value you think you're working with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try printing value of the variable `annee` first.
This might solve the problem.

Comment: yes you're right the first value returned is the header, I deleted and I solved the problem, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your example date string is accurately copied to your question there is a trailing space character at the end. The format string does not have this space, so `strptime()` is not able to parse the string. You can `strip()` the date string beforehand:

```
for line in ratings_df[['user_id','movie_id','rating','timestamp']].values:
    annee= line[3].strip()
    print datetime.strptime(annee, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Or you could add the space to the end of the format string. I think stripping is better.

Comment: no there is no space in the end in my code

Comment: Then `annee` is not what you think it is. There must be some deviation from what you've posted. Follow @deceze's advice and `print(repr(annee))` to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> annee
'1995-01-09 00:00:00 '
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(annee, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ")
datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 9, 0, 0)
```

No issues found other than extra space at the end, strip timestamp string and try again

Comment: no there is no space in the end in my code

Comment: @HamzaLahbabi - Then there is no error as well, use debugger like pdb or print the timestamp before your conversion